# GNU parallel a python script: pthread_create: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: linux, python-2.7, gnu-parallel

I tried to launch a python script (with input arguments) on a linux 
  server by using GNU parallel.

First I created my tasks_file which is like :
    python create_main.py dir1/tt1 dir2 dir3 dir4/tt1
    python create_main.py dir1/tt2 dir2 dir3 dir4/tt2
    python create_main.py dir1/tt3 dir2 dir3 dir4/tt3
    ...
  dir1/tt1 dir2 dir3 dir4/tt1 are the arguments for python script. Each
  line is a task to compute, and I have total 200 tasks in this file.

Then I tried launch each task on one node of a server in order to
  finish these 200 tasks. Here is my bash command:

```
parallel --jobs 1 --sshloginfile unique-nodelist.txt --workdir  
my_dir_to_python_script < tasks_file
```

In the unique-nodelist.txt, I defined the access to the nodes:

```
ssh -x node1;
ssh -x node2;
...
```

When I launched the above command, the computation starts to work.
  But sometimes there are error message as shown in the below:

```
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create: Cannot allocate memory
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 1024 current, 1033195 max


Traceback (most recent call last):

File "create_main.py", line 1, in <module>

from netCDF4 import Dataset
from ._netCDF4 import *
import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
from . import multi array
KeyboardInterrupt
```

After this message, then it seems to continue for other jobs. 
 In the end I checked my results, and I found that some tasks were
 carried out, but some were not computed at all.

It seems to me there are some problem to manage the memory, which
 just skipped some computation. Could you please explain to me how to
 fix this problem ? Many thanks in advance !!

Best regards

shannon

Comment: You will get bettere answers if you follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I used the following command for the parallel: parallel --jobs 1 --sshloginfile nodelist.txt --workdir  /home/codes < tasks_file.                                     In the tasks_file, I have several lines such as : python my program.py arg1 arg2.  Each line is a job to run.                                                                                                                 The purpose is to launch my python program with the arguments in different nodes. But in the end, it seems that some lines of jobs were not carried out at all. I do not understand.

Comment: You will get better answers if you follow stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (i.e. you did neither include everything that is in /home/code, the tasks_file or  what programs are installed on the servers in nodelist.txt - so your example is not complete and reproducible)